# Visual Studio Code Automatic Headers

Tags: visual-studio-code

Anyone know how to make Visual Studio Code insert a header on every new file created? For example, if I create a new file called `index.js`, the first line would be populated by something like

> Created by xxxxxxx on *insert current date*

Comment: There are plenty of extensions that can do this, find them [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) Search for "header"

Comment: @st0le Thanks for this. I found one that suits my needs!

Comment: @gogo which one did you end up using? I can't find any that automatically make them on file creation

Answer (score 0):

try License Header Manager. 
it works fine for C# under vs1015 and 2017